# OS.PATH plugins

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I need to make my plugin to read the address of another plugin. This index will vary depending on the user logged in on windows. How to make?

`plugin = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` - This path my
plugin

`D:\Users\Mike\\.qgis2\python\plugins\forceplugin` - It's Ok.

```
templates =  os.path.abspath('/.qgis2\python\plugins\gotplugin\templates)
```

This path my other plugin result:

```
C:\\.qgis2\\python\\plugins\\gotplugin\templates\
```

I want the result:

```
D:\Users\Mike\\.qgis2\python\plugins\gotplugin\templates
```

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to get the home directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/how-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
template=QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath() + "python/plugins/gotplugin/templates"
```